# SQL Server 2014 get rows through two relational tables to separate tables using id from a main table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is hard for me to explain so please feel free to let me know if further clarification is needed. I have 5 tables:

- Artwork {artwork_id, artwork_title, artwork_artist_id}
- Artwork_Insurance {artwork_id, insurance_id}
- Insurance {insurance_id, insurance_name}
- Artwork_Exhibit {artwork_id, exhibit_id}
- Exhibit {exhibit_id, exhibit_name, exhibit_start_date, exhibit_end_date}

There can be several insurances per artwork, however there can only be one active exhibit per each artwork (determined if the current date is between the start & end dates of the exhibit). My question is how do I retrieve all the artwork rows (with all the artwork table's columns), all the insurances applied to that artwork (values in insurance_name column for that artwork comma separated) as well as the exhibit_name for that artwork if one is currently active otherwise a null value is returned.

I'm pretty limited in my SQL knowledge and much of what I'm hoping to achieve isn't flushed out but here's what I have so far:

```
select distinct 
    dbo.Artwork.artwork_id, 
    dbo.Artwork.artwork_title,
    dbo.Artwork.artwork_artist_id,
    dbo.Insurance.insurance_name, 
    dbo.Exhibit.exhibit_name
from
    dbo.Artwork_Insurance
left join 
    dbo.Artwork on dbo.Artwork_Insurance.artwork_id = dbo.Artwork.artwork_id
left join 
    dbo.Insurance on dbo.Insurance.insurance_id = dbo.Artwork_Insurance.insurance_id
left join 
    dbo.Artwork_Exhibit on dbo.Artwork_Exhibit.artwork_id = dbo.Artwork.artwork_id
left join 
    dbo.Exhibit on dbo.Exhibit.exhibit_id = dbo.Artwork_Exhibit.exhibit_id;
```

However not only does this not return the same number of rows as running `select * from dbo.Artwork` but the old exhibits aren't filtered out and the insurance names aren't comma separated in the same cell together. I've done some reading on left joins but I don't think I'm using them correctly for what I'm after. I've been working on this for days and could really use some help. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, along with your current and desired outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get comma seperated insurances. It can be done in many ways. I have used `for xml`. But there other ways using `pivot` or `group + case`. And then join with other tables. I have not checked query, but it should work correctly and return your expected output

```
with cte_insurance as (
    select
        distinct Artwork_Insurance.artwork_id, stuff((
            select
                ', ' + Insurance.insurance_name
            from
                Insurance
            where
                Insurance.insurance_id = Artwork_Insurance.insurance_id
        ), 1, 2, '') insurance_name
    from
        Artwork_Insurance
)

select
    Artwork.artwork_id, Artwork.artwork_title, Artwork.artwork_artist_id
    , cte_insurance.insurance_name, Exhibit.exhibit_name
from
    Artwork
    left join cte_insurance on Artwork.artwork_id = cte_insurance.artwork_id
    left join Artwork_Exhibit on Artwork.artwork_id = Artwork_Exhibit.artwork_id
    left join Exhibit 
        on Artwork_Exhibit.exhibit_id = Exhibit.exhibit_id 
            and getdate() between Exhibit.exhibit_start_date and Exhibit.exhibit_end_date
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! I had to tweak it a bit for my use as it was returning dupes.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped